# filtering where start & end Dates between selected Date

Tags: powerpivot, powerbi, dax, ssas-tabular

I have a fact Table that contains people & Thier qualifications. The fact table has two dates, the StartStudyDate & EndStudyDate. This represents the period the students were studying.
I then have a Person Dimension, Qualification Dimension, a Grouping Dimension & one Date Dimension.

Im trying to find a count of students who were actively studying on a particular date.

In SQL its relatively simple:

```
  select a.PaygroupDescription, a.[Qualification], count(a.[PersonID])
 from  (
  select   distinct p.[PersonID], PaygroupDescription, q.[Qualification]
  from [hr].[Appointment Detail] ad
  join hr.Paygroup pg on ad.PaygroupID = pg.PaygroupID
  join hr.Qualification q on q.QualificationID = ad.QualificationID
 join hr.Person p on p.PersonID = ad.PersonID
 join dimdate sd on sd.DateID = ad.StartDateID
 join dimDate ed on ed.DateID = ad.EndDateID
  where sd.date <= 20150101 and ed.date >= 20150101
  ) as a
  group by a.PaygroupDescription, a.[Qualification]
```

The problem is i cant figure out how to do this in dax.
I started out by adding two columns to the fact table in the TabularModel:

ActualStartDate

```
    =LOOKUPVALUE(
'Date'[Date], 
'Date'[DateID],
'Appointment Detail'[StartDateID])
```

ActualEndDate

```
=LOOKUPVALUE(
'Date'[Date], 
'Date'[DateID],
'Appointment Detail'[EndDateID])
```

I then wrote the measure that checks if one date is selected from DimDate, it gets all distinct rows where the selectedDate is <= ActualStartDate && >= ActualEndDate.

Problem is that this behaves like an absolute dog. if i try to add any attributes for breaking the data down, i run out of memory (at least in 32bit excel). I know i could try 64 bit excel, but my dataset is small, so memory should not be an issue. This is before i even add filters to the calculation for specific qualifications:

```
EmployeeCount:=if(HASONEVALUE('Date'[Date]),
CALCULATE
(distinctcount('Appointment Detail'[PersonID]), 
DATESBETWEEN('Date'[Date], min('Appointment Detail'[ActualStartDate]),Max( 'Appointment Detail'[ActualEndDate]))
)
,BLANK())
```

Id appreciate help in understanding the problem correctly as im obviously missing something here regarding the problem & my dax experience is also very light.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would remove the relationships to DimDate and then use something like the following pattern for your measure:

```
EmployeeCount := CALCULATE( COUNTROWS ( 'Person' ),
 FILTER('Appointment Detail',
 'Appointment Detail'[ActualStartDate] <= MAX(DimDate[Date])
 && 'Appointment Detail'[ActualEndDate] >= MIN(DimDate[Date])
))
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! Im actually thinking though of adding another "junk" relationship between dimdate & the fact table and using via USERELATIONSHIP, so i can still use DimDate on StartDate & EndDate.

Im also thinking a better overall solution would be a calc column that says Active or NotActive, based on if the seletced date falls between the rows start and end date. this would let me see Employees who fall outside the selected dates also.

Comment: I don't think a calculated column will work - they only get evaluated during refresh.  Perhaps a measure that does COUNTROWS ( 'Person' ) - [EmployeeCount] or similar?